# JSON Parse for and while loop of multilevel array results in undefined

Tags: javascript, json, jsonparser

My script loops through different objects but I receive an undefined result from the "for" loop of the image array.

The JSON data can be viewed here: https://michaelpmullally.com/map/map.json

I have tried using different types of loops and trying to create individual variables for each item in the array.

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    console.log(myObj);
    for (i = 0; i < myObj.features.length; i++) {
        for (h = 0; h < myObj.features[i].image.length; h++) {
            var name = myObj.features[i].properties.name;
            var image = myObj.features[i].image[h]; //updated from answers !! JSON also updated
            while (h < 5) {
                var slidelink = `<a href="#` + name + `-slide-` + h + `">` + h + `</a>`;
                var slideimage = `<div class="slides">
                    <picture class="slide" id="` + name + `-slide-` + h + `">` + h + `">
                        <img src="` + image + `">
                    </picture>
                </div>`;
            }
            var slider = slidelink + slideimage;
        }
        var name = myObj.features[i].properties.name;
        var icon = myObj.features[i].properties.icon;
        var yelp = myObj.features[i].properties.yelp;
        var trip = myObj.features[i].properties.trip;
        var rating = myObj.features[i].properties.rating;
        var review = myObj.features[i].properties.content;
        document.getElementById("locations"+ i).innerHTML = `<header>
        <h2><i class="` + icon + `"></i> ` + name + `</h2>
        </header>
        <main>
            <section class="slider">`
                + slider +
           `</section> 
            <section class="review">
                <span>` + rating + `</span>
                ` + review + `
            </section>
        </main>
        <footer>
        <h2><a href="https://www.yelp.com/biz` + yelp + `"><i class="fab fa-yelp"></i></a>
        <a href="https://www.tripadvisor.com/` + trip + `"><i class="fab fa-tripadvisor"></i></a></h2>
        </footer>
        `;
    }
}
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "map.json", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

The top article block is what it should look like. https://michaelpmullally.com/map/test.html

Comment: This is unrelated but if you're using template literals, you need not use `+` add variables to strings. You can use `${variable}` For example: `\`<a href="#${name}-slide-${h}">${h}</a>`\`

Answer (score 0):

Simple mistake

```
for (h = 0; h < myObj.features[i].image.length; h++) {  <-- looping over images
  var name = myObj.features[i].properties.name;
  var image = myObj.features[i].image.file[h];  <-- using index on file[h], not image[h]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you may want to use one of the `files` described under `images` array, if so you should

```
// the index value h is on the image and not on the file
var image = myObj.features[i].image[h].file[0];  // you have misplaced your index `h`, also am simply placing the index 0 here for reference.
```

Also am unsure how and or where you are handling the different files under images, if you are then you need loop through `files array` as well

Comment: I changed the JSON data to make image the array with the image names: 
    `"image": [
       "IMG_5764.jpg",
       "IMG_5805.jpg"
     ],`
I also removed file from the code 'var image = myObj.features[i].image[h];'

Now the page doesn't load.

Comment: your image isnt loading possinly due to the relative path that you are setting  on `<img src=''>`,